# Solve the ordinary differential equation $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}F(x)=\frac{1}{F(x)^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve the ordinary differential equation
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}F(x)=\frac{1}{F(x)^2}$$
I tried simplifying and then simplifying even further and found that this function has to be in the form $e^{-cx}$ where $c$ is expressed in terms of the function itself therefore it means its a recurring function...So I need to know a function(that is not recurring) that is inversley proportional to its second derivative.I've  been trying to solve this for a long time but couldn't find anything online that was much help either.Help would be appreciated. Thanx in advance

Comment: $$
f'' f' = \frac{f'}{f^2}\Rightarrow \frac 12 (f')^2 = -\frac 1f + C_1\Rightarrow f' = \sqrt{C_2-\frac 1f}
$$

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in Cesaro's comment, the first step is
$$2F'F''=\frac{2}{F^2} \implies (F')^2=c-\frac{2}{F}.$$ Then, separating variables, $$\int \sqrt{\frac{\phantom{^1}F\phantom{^1}}{cF-2}}\; dF = x+d$$ and the standard technique is to multiply by $F$ in numerator and denominator of the fraction inside the square root: $$x+d = \int \sqrt{\frac{F^2}{cF^2-2F}}\; dF =\int \sqrt{\frac{cF^2}{(cF-1)^2-1}}\; dF. $$ If $c$ is negative, say $c=-C$, it is clearer to write this as $$x+d = \int \sqrt{\frac{CF^2}{1-(CF+1)^2}}\; dF. $$ Now substitute $cF=1\pm \cosh \theta$ in the first case, and $CF=\sin \theta -1$ in the second case. If your application requires $F$ to be positive, then only the first case, with $cF=1 +\cosh \theta$, is needed. As Travis Willse says, you won't get a closed form for $F$ in terms of $x$, in general.

Comment: thank you....but one question-if this is so hard to solve, then what is the proper equation that describes a body moving in gravity? The acceleration of an object in gravity is $a=\frac{k}{r^2}$ for some constant $k $ and since acceleration is the second derivative of $r$ doesn't that get you back to the equation in the question?

Comment: For inverse-square gravity you need $\ddot{r} = -\frac{k}{r^2}$, with $k$ positive, but this doesn't affect the conclusion that there is no closed form for $r$ in terms of $t$ except in the case where the initial speed $u$ and the initial radius $\rho$ satisfy $\rho u^2 = 2k$, which is when the particle *just* escapes to infinity.

Comment: but then how do physicists accurately predict the motion of an object in gravity? sureley there is a way, right?

Comment: Well, the solution of the differential equation gives you the time at which the particle will reach a given radius. If you want the radius at a given time, you'd have to solve numerically for r (which you can do as accurately as you like). Physicists accurately predict many things for which they don't have explicit formulae.

Answer (score 3):

If we write $y = F(x)$ and regard $x$ as a function of $y$, the differential equation becomes
$$x'' = -\frac{(x')^3}{y^2},$$
where $'$ denotes $\frac{d}{dy}$. This equation is separable and first-order in $u := x'$: Rearranging gives
$$\frac{du}{u^3} = -\frac{dy}{y^2},$$
integrating gives
$$-\frac{1}{2 u^2} = \frac{1}{y} + C,$$
and rearranging again gives
$$(x')^2 = u^2 = - \frac{1}{\frac{1}{y} + C} .$$
We can solve for $x'$ and integrate the quantity in $y$ to give an explicit formulae for $x(y)$ in elementary functions. Note that the cases $C < 0$, $C = 0$, $C > 0$ yield qualitatively different solutions. For example, for $C > 0$,
$$\boxed{x = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2} C^{3 /2}}\left[2 \sqrt{-C y (C y + 1)} + \arcsin(2 C y + 1)\right] + D} .$$

Only in the $C = 0$ case can the solutions be inverted to give explicit formulas for $y = F(x)$ in terms of elementary functions. The real solutions in that case are
$$\boxed{F(x) = -\sqrt[3]{\frac{9}{2}}(\pm x - D)^{2/3}} .$$

Incidentally, you can find the last set of solutions quickly using the ansatz $F(x) = a (\pm x)^\lambda$, which immediately forces $\lambda = \frac{2}{3}$ and then determines $a$. Then, since the differential equation is autonomous, if $F(x)$ is a solution, so is $F(x - D)$ for any constant $D$.

Comment: @TravisWilse thank you,but I have one more question.what I was trying to do by solving that equation was to find an equation that describes an objects motion under gravity. $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}F(x)=\frac{1}{F(x)^2}$$F(x)$ is the distance travelled) describes the acceleration and thats why I needed to solve it to get an accurate expression.  So does that mean that the distance travelled by an object is that very complicated function that you said is the answer to the $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}F(x)=\frac{1}{F(x)^2}$ function? if so, then doesn't that mean that the ordinary kinematic equations are wrong?

Comment: @alienare4422 mcd's comment under their answer addresses your question I think. Let me add that the case $C = 0$ corresponds to when the total energy of the system is $0$, taking the usual convention that as the distance between 2 particles $\to \infty$, the potential energy is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

It is a VERY difficult equation. If you are just interested for a solution try this by Wolfram:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}F(x)=\frac{1}{F(x)^2}$$
Reduce the order of the DE:
$$2F'\frac{d^2}{dx^2}F(x)=2\frac{F'}{F(x)^2}$$
$$F'^2=-\frac{2}{F(x)}+C$$
it's now a first order separable DE.